# Is there a way to sync xmpp messages across different devices, with standard xmpp client?

Tags: xmpp

I currently use google with a standard xmpp client, and another xmpp account is on a server of my own. I know that if I use google hangout I can get synchronized, but can I get the same feature with my own server or google's server on a standard xmpp client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is. Have a look at XEP-0280: Message Carbons
( http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0280.html )

Both your client as well as your server have to support it in order to fully work.